# How to compare the performance of languages for server programming

Tags: web, server, programming-languages

Many times see some articles said one language have better concurrency over another. One language is faster than another. One has weak computation ability on server. But how can they measure the performance of these languages? Is there any tool or task that is specially used for test performance of language in web server programming? Thanks

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're interested in. If you're talking about how many requests a server can process then you just have to setup some kind of counting mechanism then hit your server as hard as you can. After a set amount of time, stop the test and see how many requests successfully resolved. Repeat with equivalent code in each language.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you. This is one way, is there any test framework can do it?